# WooCommerce order comments - disabling use of special characters

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I'm using the following code to restrict the WooCommerce checkout inputs to alphabetical characters only (thanks to this post: [Alphabet characters only for billing and shipping names in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847084/alphabet-characters-only-for-billing-and-shipping-names-in-woocommerce)). However, this also marks each of the checkout fields as 'required' so for example even if the customer doesn't want to add any order comments, they will have to add something to complete the order. How can I edit this so that all of the fields are not required? Help much appreciated!

```
/* remove special charaters from checkout ? */

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_alphaCheckCheckoutFields');

function wh_alphaCheckCheckoutFields() {
$billing_first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_first_name');
$billing_last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_last_name');
$order_comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'order_comments');
$shipping_first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'shipping_first_name');
$shipping_last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'shipping_last_name');
$ship_to_different_address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ship_to_different_address');

if (empty(trim($billing_first_name)) || !ctype_alpha($billing_first_name)) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Billing First 
Name</strong>.'), 'error');
}
if (empty(trim($billing_last_name)) || !ctype_alpha($billing_last_name)) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Billing Last 
Name</strong>.'), 'error');
}
if (empty(trim($order_comments)) || !ctype_alpha($order_comments)) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Delivery 
Instructions</strong>.'), 'error');
}
// Check if Ship to a different address is set, if it's set then validate shipping fields.
if (!empty($ship_to_different_address)) {
    if (empty(trim($shipping_first_name)) || !ctype_alpha($shipping_first_name)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping First 
Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }
    if (empty(trim($shipping_last_name)) || !ctype_alpha($shipping_last_name)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping Last 
Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Hi Bhautik, it did seem to work but the code now also disables use of spaces between words which I will need to allow. Could it be changed to include spaces between words?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've found the answer! Change the Order comments line to the following:
if ( !empty( trim( $order_comments ) ) && !ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $order_comments)) ) {

Answer (score 0):

Change this condition

```
if (empty(trim($order_comments)) || !ctype_alpha($order_comments)) {
```

To this

```
if ( !empty( trim( $order_comments ) ) && !ctype_alpha( $order_comments ) ) {
```

Complete code

```
/* remove special charaters from checkout ? */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_alphaCheckCheckoutFields');

function wh_alphaCheckCheckoutFields() {
    $billing_first_name        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_first_name');
    $billing_last_name         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_last_name');
    $order_comments            = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'order_comments');
    $shipping_first_name       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'shipping_first_name');
    $shipping_last_name        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'shipping_last_name');
    $ship_to_different_address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ship_to_different_address');

    if ( empty( trim( $billing_first_name ) ) || !ctype_alpha( $billing_first_name ) ) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Billing First Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }

    if ( empty( trim( $billing_last_name ) ) || !ctype_alpha( $billing_last_name )) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Billing Last Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }

    if ( !empty( trim( $order_comments ) ) && !ctype_alpha( $order_comments ) ) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Delivery Instructions</strong>.'), 'error');
    }

    // Check if Ship to a different address is set, if it's set then validate shipping fields.
    if ( !empty( $ship_to_different_address ) ) {
        if ( empty( trim( $shipping_first_name ) ) || !ctype_alpha( $shipping_first_name ) ) {
            wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping First  Name</strong>.'), 'error');
        }

        if ( empty( trim( $shipping_last_name ) ) || !ctype_alpha( $shipping_last_name ) ) {
            wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping Last  Name</strong>.'), 'error');
        }
    }
}
```